# What is $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\ln(\sin x)dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is the value of $$\int_0^{\Large \frac{\pi}2}\ln(\sin x)dx=\text{?}$$
Can this be done using by parts?

Answer (score 2):

Notice, let $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x)\ dx\tag 1$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\right)\ dx$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\cos x\right)\ dx\tag 2$$
adding (1) & (2), 
$$I+I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin x\right)\ dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\cos x\right)\ dx$$
$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin x\cos x\right)\ dx$$
$$I=\frac 12\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{2 \sin x\cos x}{2}\right)\ dx$$
$$I=\frac 12\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin 2x\right)\ dx-\frac 12\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(2\right)\ dx$$
$$I=\frac 14\int_0^{\pi}\ln\left(\sin x\right)\ dx-\frac 12\ln\left(2\right)\int_0^{\pi/2}\ dx$$
$$I=\frac 12\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin x\right)\ dx-\frac 12\ln\left(2\right)\cdot \frac \pi2$$
$$I=\frac I2-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln(2)$$
$$\frac I2=\color{}{-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln(2)}$$
$$\color{red}{I=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)}$$

Comment: Good lord, why do u answer this question which has already been answerd hundreds of times?

Answer (score 2):

Let $$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\ln(\sin x)dx$$
Using $$\int _a^b f(x)dx=\int _a^b f(a+b-x) dx$$
We get 
$$ I= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\ln(\cos x)dx$$
Adding,
$$\implies 2I= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}[\ln(\sin x)+\ln(\cos x)]dx$$
$$\implies 2I= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\ln(\frac{\sin 2x}{2})dx$$
$$\implies 2I= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\ln(\sin 2x)dx-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\ln 2dx$$
$$\implies 2I= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin t)dt-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2$$
Using $$\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin x)dx=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin x)dx$$
We get 
$$2I=I-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2$$
$$\implies I= -\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2$$